# How to import ts file on js file firebase-functions

Tags: typescript, firebase, require, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to import my ts file on some js file,
when I am doing deploy I am getting error:

> Error: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module 'EmailData'

My code:

the js file:

```
var EmailDataClass = require("EmailData");
```

the ts file:

```
class EmailData {}
export EmailData;
```

Comment: Where are you putting your module?  In the node_modules directory?  Should look like : `myFirebaseApp/functions/node_modules/EmailData/index.ts`

Comment: node_modules if for npm packages and my files on the same folder as index...

Comment: Firebase does not automatically interpret or transpile typescript. You'll have to transpile it yourself and deploy the resulting JavaScript module to Cloud Functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973741/typescript-transpiling-to-javascript-for-firebase-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good introduction: [link](https://hackernoon.com/configuring-typescript-compiler-a84ed8f87e3) node_modules folder. But only the index.js file is executed, you can reconfigure a main file through the main field of functions/package.json. You can see the source code from  [link](https://github.com/laurenzlong/say-that/tree/master/functions)