# How to import a variable from .ts file to .js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, protractor

For my project, i require to import a variable declared in .ts file to use in .js file. I cannot change js file to ts file as there are other functions written in it which will get impacted.

I tried a lot using:

```
import AvailableBalances = require('./app.Processing');

import { AvailableBalances } from './app.Processing';
```

but nothing helped. Below is my code in .ts file. 'Comment' is the variable for example, i need to import and use in .js file.

```
describe('Login', function () {
it('Should able to login into the Webpage', function () {

browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
browser.get('https://inside.pilot.theprincipal.net/rnqLiabilityManagement/');
var Comment = 'Login Successful';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44263497/how-to-import-ts-file-on-js-file-firebase-functions

Comment: @swit I looked upon the link however, my .ts file is a test case file which is written in 'describe' and 'it' format. and under that, i have declared a variable which i need to use in my config file (.js). I'm not using classes in .ts file

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what is `.ts` and how JavaScript modules work:

The `.ts` file is a file writtent in TypeScript and that need a TypeScript runtime to be evaluated (and used).

JavaScript modules is a bit complex as there is a lot of things to understand. First of all, not all runtime (JavaScript evaluator) can compute modules import/export. Secondary, if you set up everything to import modules in JavaScript, you need to be ware that it can miss something to import TypeScript files.

You did not give so much information about your tools. But if you use Webpack, it is mandatory to add a "TypeScript loader" in order to import TypeScript modules into JavaScript modules.

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Thank you for the information @enguerran. I'm using visual studio code tool. Do i need to add any loader which converts .ts to .js at runtime?

Comment: I don't know what tools from visual studio code you use. But here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/k0qyrq7yr. CodeSandBox uses `parcel` as the build tool that is responsible to import modules. See the exported github project to see the configuration: https://github.com/enguerran/tsmoduleinjsmodule/blob/master/package.json#L7

Comment: Take a look on the TypeScript documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html and be sure to understand this tutorial: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html

Comment: the example you gave, consists of exporting a function and functions are not declared in describe block in node. I just wanted to declare a variable in .ts for example    var comment = 'hello' and use this 'comment' in .js file

Comment: Take the time to understand your needs and the basis of your activity. Functions and variables are exported the same way (of course hence functions are expression that can be stored in variables). To give you the chance to try it by yourself, I illustrated my comment in the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/k0qyrq7yr

Comment: Thanks for the example, i tried it but I'm getting error:     [19:34:13] 
    E/configParser - Error code: 105
    [19:34:13] E/configParser - Error message: failed loading configuration file protractor.conf.js
[19:34:13] E/configParser - C:\Shruti\Git\Manual_Distrib_F1\rnqliabilitymanagement\protractor.conf.js:8
import { comment } from "./e2e/app.Login";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)

Comment: I tried using import { comment } from require( './e2e/app.Login'); but nothing helped.

Comment: I'll take another look at this if you update the question with complete information about what you're trying now.